# Check for partial string matches between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, substring

I have 2 dataframes

df1 has a list of Strings

```
    print(df1)  
        Strings
    0   AppleSauce
    1   SauceMangoSauce
    2   StrawberrySauce
```

df2 gives a list of Fruits

```
    print(df2)  
        Sub_Strings
    0   Banana
    1   Mango
```

I want to flag any Strings in df1 that have contain one of the substrings from df2

```
    print(df1)  
        Strings          Flag
    0   AppleSauce        False 
    1   SauceMangoSauce   True
    2   StrawberrySauce   False
```

I am not sure what the right syntax is for the below piece of code which i know is incorrect

```
df1.loc[df1['Strings'].contains(df2['Sub_Strings']), 'Flag'] = True
```

thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
# create a regex
query = '|'.join(df2['Sub_S'].tolist())

# find matches
df1['Flag'] = df1['Strings'].str.contains(query)

print(df1)

           Strings   Flag
0       AppleSauce  False
1  SauceMangoSauce   True
2  StrawberrySauce  False
```